# How do i do this through Shell Scripting?

Tags: shell

When i give the below  command , it interacts with my database and give me the desired reults:-

```
        isql -Usa -Pbas11 -Dsmdb

       1>select distinct user_name from jobs
       2>go
```

This fetch me the desired result. Here `bas11` being the password and `smdb` being my database.

I want to do the same through Shell Script And redirect the O/P of this Sybase command to filesay /tmp/output.txt 
The Shell Script i wrote is this :-

```
       #!/bin/sh
       isql -Usa -Psybase11 -Dcnadb << ./ritesh.txt  > /tmp/output.txt
```

here ./ritesh txt which is input to sybase command contain :-

```
    select distinct user_name from jobs go
```

But i am not geeting any output in /tmp/output.txt after executing this Shell Script . 
I am new to Shell Script . Can anyone help me here ? 
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: First I suggest you format the code in your questions a little better (like linebreaks where there really are linebreaks). Then you might test if your script works better if you instead of `<<` use just `<`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sybase if you want the query output in a file then do as below:

```
isql -Uuser -Sserver -Ppassword -imy.sql -oresults.csv
```

Also, if its shell you can do something like this in shell,

```
isql -Uuser -Sserver -Ppassword -imy.sql -oresults.csv << END
yoursql
go
END
```